# How can Check the Value of the two array with different values,size in php

Tags: php

I need a Help, i try to check the array value to another array value.The two array size many be different all the time.because the array get from the data base.
Example

```
array A     array B    Result
  1          1,2,3      true
  1            2,3      false
  1            2        false
  1,2          2,3      false
  1,2,3        1        false
  2,3         2,3       true
  1,2,3       1,2,3     true

$arrayA=array(1,2);
$arrayB=array(1);
```

the array value same time different

```
 $arrayA=array(1);
 $arrayB=array(1,2,3);
```

The array hole value in the second array then only return true. I need to check the all the value of array a to next array b. please help me.thank adv....

Comment: i was try to make check the every single  values of the first array will compare with  every single of the next array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = !array_diff($arrayA, $arrayB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);

Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
?>
```

You can get all the info [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: i don't want print the array if the 1st array value in the second array like array a 1 in array b 1,2 then return true in case of array a 2 the second array 2,3 return false.

Comment: Isn't that what my answer does? When `array_diff(...)` returns an empty array, `!array_diff(...)` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

just a rough idea,

```
<?
$arrayA=array(1);
 $arrayB=array(1,2,3); 
 $k=array_intersect($arrayA,$arrayB);
 print_r($k);
?>
```

Comment: Best practice recommendation: always use the long-style PHP tag -- `<?php` rather than just `<?`.